# How to use "." correctly in SQL expression in VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

```
sql = "SELECT 'data1$'.'YEAR','data1$'.'GDP','data2$'.'PERCENT OF GOVERNMENT CONSUMPTION(%)'
```

`from 'data1$'inner join 'data2$' on 'data1$'.'YEAR'='data2$'.'Statistic Year'"`

I have two sheets in the same workbook,data1 and data2. I try to find the same year with GDP and Government CONSUMPTION then I try to use SQL to firgure it out.

Obviously should use inner join here.

But when I try to run this code in VBA, it told me "invalid use of '.','!'or'()'in query expression"

Comment: is your table literally called data$?

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = "SELECT data1$.YEAR, data1$.GDP, data2$.[PERCENT OF GOVERNMENT CONSUMPTION(%)] FROM data1$ inner join data2$ on data1$.YEAR = data2$.[Statistic Year]"
```

This is what I can gather from your post what your sql statement should look like. There's no need to have all those extra single quotes.

Let me know if i got it completely wrong